# Zurb foundation table customization

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a Foundation table that I want to customize. I have managed to remove alternate row colors, set background color and remove border with this:

```
table{
  background: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  border: none;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

yet, it won't change the text color. Why is this happening and what do I need to do to change it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your selector is prob not specific enough. use inspector/firebug to find out what selector foundation use. so you can match it and change it.

Comment: for example `#id` > `.class` `td` > `tr`

Comment: the more specific the selector is, it will override the less specific one.

Comment: and what come after will be more important to what come before.  so make sure your external css link is place after foundation.css file.

Comment: are you trying to change this in the _settings.scss or where?

Comment: wlin: right, silly me, that was it! thank you.